# Missing argument for closure with optional parameter

Tags: parameters, closures, laravel, laravel-4, option-type

I am in the process of working my way through a couple tutorials for Laravel 4 and I have run into a snag that I cannot figure out or comprehend as to why it is running incorrectly.

What I am trying to do compose a route that looks at the URL, and then works logically based on that. Here is my current code:

```
Route::get('/books/{genre?}', function($genre)  
{  
    if ($genre == null) return 'Books index.';  
    return "Books in the {$genre} category.";  
});
```

So if the URL is `http://localhost/books`, the page should return "Books index." If the URL reads `http://localhost/books/mystery` the page should return "Books in the mystery category."

However I am getting a 'Missing argument 1 for {closure}()' error. I have even referred to the Laravel documentation and they have their parameters formated exactly the same way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the genre is optional, you have to define a default value:

```
Route::get('/books/{genre?}', function($genre = "Scifi")  
{  
    if ($genre == null) return 'Books index.';  
    return "Books in the {$genre} category.";  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Works like a charm.

Comment: You can also supply a `defaults` to the route, so `Route::get('books/{genre?}', function($genre) { return $genre; })->defaults('genre', 'mystery');`

Comment: wrong cause if genre is null, genre will have "Scifi" value into last function. you can realize that "Books index' never will be showed

Answer (score 1):

Genre is optional, you must define a default value to `$genre`. `$genre=null` so that it matches for **"Book index"** of your code.

```
Route::get('books/{genre?}', function($genre=null)
{
    if (is_null($genre)) 
        return "Books index";


return "Books in the {$genre} category";
});
```